# How do you convert __asm blocks to string-based asm (compatible with G++)?

Tags: c++, assembly, g++

I recently found a C++ library that would be perfect for my project, but it defines two functions that use __asm blocks that can only be compiled in VC++:

```
// upper 32-bit result of 32x32-bit product
inline unsigned Product_64(unsigned l, unsigned c)
{
  _asm {
    mov eax,l
    mul c
    mov eax,edx
  }
} // return value in register EAX

// division of 64-bit (after scaling) by a 32-bit number
inline unsigned Division_64(unsigned dvh, unsigned dvr)
{
  _asm {
    xor eax,eax
    not eax
    mov edx,dvh
    div dvr
  }
} // return value in register EAX
```

The problem with this is that I need to compile the project with G++, which uses string based asm blocks. Given that I don't have the time to properly learn assembly, is there:

1. A script that will reliably converts to G++'s string asm
2. A way of rewriting this function in C++ to the same effect
3. A list of simple instructions on how to convert between the two formats

Thanks!

Comment: Why not rewrite the code in C++ and trust your compiler to generate sane machine code?

Answer (score 1):

You're requesting two things here:

- conversion between Intel ASM syntax and AT&T syntax. See for example http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq17_2.html
- converting between calling conventions. VC++ always assumes the return value to be in EAX, for example. In G++, you can specify more intricate behaviour between C++ and asm.

Rewriting these two function to C++ (untested, assuming a compiler where 'long long' is 64 bits):

- Product_64: return (int)(((long long)l * c) >> 32);
- Division_64: return (int)(((((long long)dvh) << 32) + ~(long long)0) / dvr);

Comment: Converting between Intel and AT&T syntax isn't necessary. GCC has the `-masm=intel` option. Also, GCC doesn't support assembly code which just happens to set the correct register. The assembly code would need to be modified to store the result in a local variable, and then return that local variable. (If done correctly, and if optimising, the generated code will not contain references to that local variable.)